# How to filter dataset to not include data with pickup and dropoff times outside of range

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have a dataset of NYC taxi data that I am trying to filter through.  The dataset has the schema like this:

```
root
 |-- medallion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hack_license: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vendor_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rate_code: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- store_and_fwd_flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pickup_datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- dropoff_datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- passenger_count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- trip_time_in_secs: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- trip_distance: double (nullable = true)
 |-- pickup_longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- pickup_latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- dropoff_longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- dropoff_latitude: double (nullable = true)
```

I want to filter the dataset so that any entries which have pickup and dropoff times not between the hours of 9am to 5pm are excluded. But I am having trouble writing a helper method to use within a `withColumn` function.  Here is what I have for the `withColumn` calls:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as fun

taxi_raw.withColumn("pickup_datetime", remove_pickup_times(fun.col("pickup_datetime"))
taxi_raw.withColumn("dropoff_datetime", remove_dropoff_times(fun.col("dropoff_datetime"))
```

And here is what I have for the helper methods so far:

```py
import datetime

def remove_pickup_times(pickup_datetime):
    time_start = datetime.time(9,0,0)
    time_end = datetime.time(17,0,0)
    if(pickup_datetime.time() >= time_start and pickup_datetime.time() <= time_end):
        //insert code to remove entry from dataset

def remove_dropoff_times(dropoff_datetime):
        time_start = datetime.time(9,0,0)
        time_end = datetime.time(17,0,0)
        if(dropoff_datetime.time() >= time_start and dropoff_datetime.time() <= time_end):
            //insert code to remove entry from dataset
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use native Spark functions. [`date_format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) when 'HH:mm:ss' format is provided will only extract the time.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2020-01-01 08:08:08', '2020-01-01 09:09:09'),
     ('2020-01-01 16:08:08', '2020-01-01 17:09:09'),
     ('2020-01-01 16:08:08', '2020-01-01 16:09:09'),
     ('2020-01-01 20:08:08', '2020-01-01 20:09:09')],
    ['pickup_datetime', 'dropoff_datetime'])
```

Script for trips outside work hours:

```py
start = F.date_format('pickup_datetime', 'HH:mm:ss')
end = F.date_format('dropoff_datetime', 'HH:mm:ss')
df = df.filter((end < '09:00:00') | (start > '17:00:00'))

df.show()
# +-------------------+-------------------+
# |    pickup_datetime|   dropoff_datetime|
# +-------------------+-------------------+
# |2020-01-01 20:08:08|2020-01-01 20:09:09|
# +-------------------+-------------------+
```

Script for trips during work hours:

```py
start = F.date_format('pickup_datetime', 'HH:mm:ss')
end = F.date_format('dropoff_datetime', 'HH:mm:ss')
df = df.filter((start >= '09:00:00') & (end <= '17:00:00'))

df.show()
# +-------------------+-------------------+
# |    pickup_datetime|   dropoff_datetime|
# +-------------------+-------------------+
# |2020-01-01 16:08:08|2020-01-01 16:09:09|
# +-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark internally stores the timestamp as Epoch Milliseconds. So you can cast the timestamp to long and do the checks.

Try this spark.sql

```
spark.sql(s"""
with t1 ( select '2020-01-01 08:08:08' pickup , '2020-01-01 09:09:09' drop union all 
          select '2020-01-01 16:08:08', '2020-01-01 17:09:09' union all
          select '2020-01-01 16:08:08', '2020-01-01 16:09:09' union all
          select '2020-01-01 20:08:08', '2020-01-01 20:09:09' ) ,
    t2 ( select to_timestamp(pickup) pickup, to_timestamp(drop) drop  from t1  )
    select pickup, drop  from t2
     where (
             cast(drop as long) < cast(date_trunc('DAY',pickup) as long) + (9*60*60) --  09:00:00
             or
             cast(pickup as long) > cast(date_trunc('DAY',pickup) as long) + (17*60*60) --  17:00:00
            ) 
""").show(false)

+-------------------+-------------------+
|pickup             |drop               |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2020-01-01 20:08:08|2020-01-01 20:09:09|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```